# How can I execute commands in git-bash in Windows which are located in a folder with spaces ie "Program Files"?

Tags: windows, cmd, git-bash

When I use git bash, from time to time I want to invoke a command which is on my `$PATH` ( well actually on my `%PATH%` )  but if the command resides somewhere in a folder with spaces on it, it fails to run.

For instance if the program is on `C:\Program Files\whatever\aCmd.exe` and I type `aCmd` on bash, it says "Program" is not a valid program and such.

What I did was to re-install the program in a folder without spaces, but recently my coworkers are starting to leave git-gui and are using git-bash and the recurrent question is "How do I execute aCmd" and when I tell them to re-install it they go like ¬¬

Q. How can I execute commands in git-bash which are located in a folder with spaces?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just put the command to execute between double quotes, like so

```
"C:\Program Files\whatever\aCmd.exe"
```

Answer (score 4):

To reach the directory which has the spaces in it's path you just need to wrap the whole path with quotes. It should look like this:

```
cd "/c/Some Folder/Some Other Folder/"
```

Answer (score 4):

Where there are **special characters** in a file name (spaces, $, parenthesis...) you need to **place a backslash ahead of the character** so that it reads it as is.

For example, if you want to run the program notepad++.exe straight from Bash and need to direct the path to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\
```

Then you would code the path in your bash.rc file as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++:<path2>:<path3>:...<pathn>:
```

Note the backslashes leading the spaces and parentheses.

You can even add an additional line on the next line of your bash.rc file:

```
alias npp=notepad++
```

which will **create a shortcut**, allowing you to type **npp** straight into Bash, instead of having to type out the full program name **notepad++** every time.

I'm a total noob, just started coding 4 days ago, though I found for this problem the best website was the following:  **http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Quote.html**

Hope this helps! :D

Answer (score 1):

Commands in git-bash accept paths within double quotes

`"C:\Program Files\whatever\aCmd.exe"`

or back slash for scaping the blank space

`c/Program\ Files/whatever/aCmd.exe`

Hope it helps!