# How to launch this program from the command line?

Tags: windows, cmd, operating-system, executable

This is the program I am trying to launch from command line (Star Guard)
[image]

I opened a new command prompt process in this directory and am trying to start the Star Guard application with command line(so I can pass in command line arguments later).

However when I do so, I don't end up launching the program but I do end up launching a new command prompt process in the same directory.(output shown below) The program launches fine when I start it normally(GUI click)
[image]

Does anyone know what the issue is? I first did the ls(OSx) [equivalent](http://skimfeed.com/blog/windows-command-prompt-ls-equivalent-dir/) in Windows to make sure I had the right file path for the executable. I then used the [start](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) command to start the program along with [enclosing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641458/how-can-i-execute-commands-in-git-bash-in-windows-which-are-located-in-a-folder) the executable path in quotation marks to account of the spaces.

Comment: That comma looks odd, did you try executing `"Star Guard.exe"` from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the `start` command is unique, not to mention daft.  If the first argument is in quotes it is interpreted as a window title.

In this case, you don't actually need to use `start` at all, you could just say

```
"Star Guard"
```

or

```
"Star Guard.exe"
```

If you want to use `start`, perhaps because you want to specify `/wait` for a GUI application or because you want to launch a console application in a new window, you have to include the title argument:

```
start "" "Star Guard.exe"
```

(The title argument doesn't need to actually specify a title, it just needs to be present.)

Comment: This goes back to [`start` in OS/2 cmd.exe](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/os2start.php) circa 1987. However, in OS/2 `start` had a `/PGM` option to force interpreting a quoted string as the command instead of the title.

Answer (score 1):

From OS/2 Warp Help

```
 Starts an OS/2 program in another session. 

 The primary use for START is to automatically start programs at system startup.  The 
 special batch file, STARTUP.CMD, allows you to do this. 

 To imbed redirectional signals into the command session, enclose the command and 
 command inputs in quotation marks. 

 START 
          "program         /K        /F 
          title"         /C        /B 
                             /N 


           /PGM          /FS         /MAX 
                             /WIN        /MIN 
                             /PM  
                             /DOS 

  command 
            /I                         command   
                                         inputs  






 Related Commands:  RUN 

 Enter this command without a parameter to start an OS/2 command processor. 

 If you use the /WIN, /FS, or /PM parameter, your program runs in the foreground session.  
 If you do not use one of these parameters, you can use the /F parameter to make the 
 program run in the foreground session. 

 Make sure that you specify the correct drive and path when you use the START command to 
 run a batch file with the STARTUP.CMD file.  Also, if you plan to redirect I/O using the 
 START command, enclose the command and command inputs within quotation marks. 

 You can use START to run full-screen applications or applications running in a window 
 such as Presentation Manager programs. 

 START determines the type of application and will run it in the appropriate window or 
 full-screen session.  However, you have the option to override the determined default by 
 using the /FS, /WIN, /PM, or /I parameter. 

 You cannot start a batch file (.CMD) with the /PM parameter.
```