# Run brunch from different directory and use relative paths

Tags: javascript, git, git-submodules, brunch

We want to use the same build system across multiple projects. I have a working brunch configuration file that I want to put in a git submodule, so that that submodule can be referenced in multiple projects and changes are easily propagated (less fragile than copy and paste and sets authoritative source of brunch-config.js).

Putting brunch-config.js in a git submodule though causes my folder structure to end up like this:

```
WebApp // git root
|---Brunch-Build-System // git submodule
|   |---brunch-config.js
|---node_modules
|---source // all the source code I want compiled
```

Brunch operates assuming brunch-config.js would be at the same or higher level than the source being compiled. In this setup, this is not the case. I've tried modifying my brunch-config.js to use a relative path to no avail. Here is my `files` block of the Brunch configuration as it currently stands, without any relative path attempt:

```
files: {
  javascripts: {
    joinTo: {
      'js/lib.js': /^(?!source\/)/
    },
    entryPoints: {
      'source/scripts/app.jsx': {
        'js/app.js': /^source\//
      },
    }
  },
  stylesheets: {joinTo: 'css/core.css'}
}
```

How could I modify this to use a relative path given the desired folder structure above? Is this even possible?

Comment: AFIK, Brunch supports relative paths. Did you try it on another OS?

Comment: I have not, but we require this to run on Windows, which is what I tried it on. How would I integrate a relative path into the existing regex? @JohannesFilter

Comment: Hey Scott, did you take a look at my answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

A submodule needs to be associates with a root folder within the parent repo: it is the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the main repo index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) which records which SHA1 that submodule is checked out.

In your case, it would be best if you can use, in a [post-checkout hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout), a script ensuring there is a **symbolic link** between:

- `brunch-config.js` at its correct place and
- that `Brunch-Build-System / brunch-config.js` from the submodule

The lines to include in the hook would be something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -e /correct/path/for/brunch-config.js ]; then
  ln -s /correct/path/for/brunch-config.js Brunch-Build-System/brunch-config.js
fi
```

Although the OP being on Windows:

> I ended up just programmatically copying the file over and gitignoreing the copied file

Comment: Could you include the line(s) I would put in the post-checkout hook to make the symlink?

Comment: @ScottH I have edited the answer with a idea of what the hook might look like

Comment: Thanks but when using this on Windows 10 it seems to copy the file rather than creating a symbolic link like `mklink` does. Any thoughts? Also I had to switch the order of the arguments for the `ln` command.

Comment: Then you can actually use the mklink, if you are running it as admin. If not, use mklink /J.

Comment: I'm having trouble using `mklink` as part of the bash script though, it says "Command not found".

Comment: @ScottH Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/10642325/6309 in order to call `cmd /C "mklink /J ..."`

Comment: As I cannot run this as an administrator, I will need the `/J` flag. I'm working on how to use that as that is a directory junction and not a symbolic link, suggestions welcome. Can you edit your answer to reflect the things we have discussed, including the Windows/Linux differences and that your `ln` commands seem to be out of order?

Comment: When I try `mklink /J` with a file it creates something but double clicking it results in popup error "The directory name is invalid". There seems to be a substantial difference between symbolic links and junctions, see [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042542/what-is-the-difference-between-ntfs-junction-points-and-symbolic-links#answer-9042600). I need to be able to link to effectively have brunch-config.js at root, which seems accomplishable only with a symbolic link, which I need admin permissions for. Perhaps I should just copy the file on checkout and git ignore it.

Comment: @ScottH yes, this is expected: the goal is not to double click. The goal is for a program needing to access that file to be able to read it through this (directory) junction which could work for a file too.

Comment: Even though the junction seemed to produce a case such that when `cat`ed I could see the file, `brunch build` did nothing - no errors, no compilation, no nothing. I ended up just programmatically copying the file over and `gitignore`ing the copied file.

Comment: @ScottH OK. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

In general, brunch supports relative paths. But in order to make it work, you have to first make sure that the other folders are `watched`. See [this part in the docs](http://brunch.io/docs/config#-paths-). For your case, add this to your config.

```
paths = {
  watched: ['../source', '../node_modules'],
}
```

Then prepend the RegExs by `..\/`.

```
joinTo: {
  'js/lib.js': /^..\/(?!source\/)/
},
entryPoints: {
  'source/scripts/app.jsx': {
    'js/app.js': /^..\/source\//
  },
}
```

Instead of a RegEx, you can also write a function that takes the path as an argument and has to return whether the path should be included or not. See [this part in the docs](http://brunch.io/docs/config#pattern-matching).

Comment: I just got to try this and it prompted me to have a package.json with the brunch libraries in them. This required installing brunch npm packages in the submodule. Brunch building ran for a while, saying it was compiling but eventually I ended up with a "JavaScript heap out of memory" error.

Comment: Wait, you want the `package.json` to be outside of the submodule, right?

Comment: It seems that in order to make it work, the `package.json` and thus the `node_modules` have to be in the submodule folder since you cannot change the default `node_modules` location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json/26293141#26293141